# Visual Assist Filtering Toolbar doesnt show up

Tags: resharper, intellisense, visual-studio-2013, visual-assist

I have visual studio 2013, latest resharper and latest visual assist. I install visual assist because visual assist intellisense and code colouring features are way better than resharper and I just cant live without it. I install resharper because resharper have a lot of practical productivity tools that visual assist doesnt provide. The problem I have with this setup is that visual assist intellisense features is disable even after I disable resharper intellisense features.

My question is, how can I enable visual assist intellisense features without uninstalling resharper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Resharper 5 and newer versions by using the Suspend button in

```
  Tools > Options > Resharper
```

Version 2001 of Visual Assist X supports Visual Studio 2013 RC only.
http://www.wholetomato.com/support/history.asp

Comment: I did try that and still no filtering toolbar. Shame.

Comment: You might need to wait for a version of Visuaol Assist that works with VS 2013.